# Highcharts synchronize tooltip on multiple charts with multiple series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to synchronize shared tooltip across multiple charts, each having multiple series.

The problem is in the below example, the tooltip always shows the 3 series, even though at that particular point there are only two series present.

1) How do I make sure that a series is shown in tooltip only when it is actually present?

2) How do I make sure the tooltip is closed when we move out of the chart?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qoL7fx27/1/

Code for synchronization in fiddle:

```
$('#container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function (e) {
    var chart,
        point,
        i,
        event;

    for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i = i + 1) {
        chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
        var points = [];
        // Find coordinates within the chart
        event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent);
        // Get the hovered point
        for(var j=0; j<chart.series.length; j++) {
           point = chart.series[j].searchPoint(event, true);
           points.push(point);  
        }

        chart.tooltip.refresh(points);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my solution. It's perfectly working for me. I made adjustments based on [Synchronisation of multiple charts](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/snippets/synchronisation-of-multiple-charts/)

[Demo here](https://codepen.io/lzl124631x/pen/KLEdby?editors=0010)

[image: effect]

The following code shows/hides the tooltip and makes sure they are aligned on `mousemove` and `mouseleave`.

Note that I found that I only need to find the first point searched and use it to show/hide the tooltip. It's because all my time series share the same x values.

```
$("#container").bind("mousemove mouseleave", function(e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; ++i) {
    let hart = Highcharts.charts[i];
    let event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent); // Find coordinates within the chart
    let point;
    for (let j = 0; j < chart.series.length && !point; ++j) {
      point = chart.series[j].searchPoint(event, true);
    }
    if (!point) return;

    if (e.type === "mousemove") {
       point.onMouseOver();
      chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, point); // Show the crosshair
    } else {
      point.onMouseOut();
      chart.tooltip.hide(point);
      chart.xAxis[0].hideCrosshair();
    }

  }
});
```

Keep reseting the `reset` function so as to disallow HighCharts resetting the points -- we take over the control.

```
Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function() {
  return undefined;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

> 1) How do I make sure that a series is shown in tooltip only when it is actually present?

The unwanted behavior is caused by `searchPoint` function - it returns the nearest point even though the x position doesn't mach with other points. So if the series has only one point it'll be always found.

**Solution:**

Manually select points to display in `tooltip.formatter`:

```
        formatter: function() {
          var outputString = '';

          this.points.forEach(function(point) {
            if (point.x === this.x) {
              outputString += "<span style='color:" + point.color + "'>\u25CF</span> " + point.series.name + ": <b>" + point.y + "</b><br/>";
            }
          }, this);
          return outputString;
        }
```

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

---

> 2) How do I make sure the tooltip is closed when we move out of the chart?

<s>Restore the default `Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset` function by removing these lines:</s>

```
Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function() {
  return undefined;
};
```

---

**Demo for both questions:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2mxxrk5n/

---

### **Update:**

I posted the wrong answer for the second question. This code hides tooltips:

```
$('#container').bind('mouseout', function(e) {
  Highcharts.charts.forEach(function(chart) {
    chart.tooltip.hide();
    // undo point highlight
    chart.series.forEach(function(series) {
        series.points.forEach((point) => point.setState(''));
    });
  });
});
```

---

> can you please tell me how to highlight the corresponding points in each chart? As of now, the tooltip shows correctly, however the points are not highlighted in three charts

This piece of highlights points:

```
points.forEach(function(point_) {
  if (point_) {
    point_.highlight(e);
  }
}, this);
```

To achieve the desired behavior you must provide a logic for filtering points that should be Highlighted. Here's a very simplified example adjusted to this particular case:

```
// provide a logic for filtering points
if(points[0] && points[1].x > 0) {
    points.pop(); // remove the unwanted point
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. One more question, can you please tell me how to highlight the corresponding points in each chart?  As of now, the tooltip shows correctly, however the points are not highlighted in three charts

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. I'm sorry for bugging you - the chart points seem to be still hi-lighted even after moving out of the chart and tooltip closes. Apart from that, thanks a ton for helping me with this.

Comment: No problem ;) I updated my answer and fiddle. 3 lines after `// undo point highlight` comment fix this issue.